# How to Return Null for Duplicated Rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this address in my query:

```
CASE    
   WHEN  olnn.olnnNote like '%SEE DRAWING%'  
     THEN  'Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\Custom Cabs\' + 'CUSTOM' + '_' + CAST (olnav.olnavValue as nvarchar(25)) +  '.jpg'   --Added 2018-05-23 by MA  
   ELSE Null        
END AS imageFilePath
```

[image: Here is the result]

And it results to duplicated file paths because of duplicated cells in olnn.olnnNote. I tried to use SELECT DISTINCT CASE but I still ended up with the same results.

Any one knows my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: You need to provide sample data and results that show the duplication.  A database tag is also recommended.

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Do you have another column beside distinct case? could you provide all query?

Comment: I suggest you post data to reproduce the problem.  The question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

First, you never need to include ELSE NULL in a CASE statement since NULL is the default value when no conditions are met.

To get the desired results you can use ROW_NUMBER, PARTITION BY the rows that you don't want duplicated, then return your file path when the ROW_NUMBER = 1. Note the following sample data and solution:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @olnn TABLE (olnavValue varchar(20), olnnNote varchar(1000));
INSERT @olnn (olnavValue, olnnNote) VALUES 
('abc', 'blah blah SEE DRAWING'),
('abc', 'blah SEE DRAWING blah blah'),
('xxx', 'blah blah blah blah... SEE DRAWING') ,
('yyy', 'SEE DRAWING Please'),
('zzz', 'blah blah blah blah... SEE DRAWING'),
('zzz', 'yada yada... SEE DRAWING'),
('zzz', 'SEE DRAWING');

-- Solution    
WITH olnn AS 
(
  SELECT 
    olnn.olnavValue,
    olnn.olnnNote,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY olnn.olnavValue ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM @olnn olnn
)
SELECT 
  olnn.olnavValue,
  FilePath = 
    CASE WHEN olnn.olnnNote LIKE '%SEE DRAWING%' AND olnn.rn = 1 
         THEN 'Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\Custom Cabs\' + 'CUSTOM' + '_' +
           CAST(olnn.olnavValue as nvarchar(25)) +  '.jpg' 
  END
FROM olnn;
```

**Results**

```
olnavValue           FilePath
-------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc                  Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\Custom Cabs\CUSTOM_abc.jpg
abc                  NULL
xxx                  Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\Custom Cabs\CUSTOM_xxx.jpg
yyy                  Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\Custom Cabs\CUSTOM_yyy.jpg
zzz                  Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\Custom Cabs\CUSTOM_zzz.jpg
zzz                  NULL
zzz                  NULL
```

Note that, in you have not specified what you would like to see when olnnNote is not like '%SEE DRAWING%'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I set rn as you did, but when I try to call rn=1 it doesnt let me to and says invalid column name:                                                                        `, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY olnn.olnnNote ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                                                        
`,CASE WHEN  olnn.olnnNote like '%SEE DRAWING%' AND rn = 1
  THEN 'Y:\300 ORDER PROCESSING\Majid Ahmadi\Custom Cabs\' + 'CUSTOM' + '_'  + CAST (olnav.olnavValue as nvarchar(25)) +  '.jpg'  --Added 2018-05-23 by MA
  ELSE Null 
  END AS imageFilePath`